# Full width CSS grid item using place-content: center

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using CSS grid's `place-content: center` to vertically and horizontally center a div in a fixed container, like so:

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">Some content here</div>
</div>
```

I would like the inner div to be full width, with a maximum width of 500px but it doesn't seem to respect the `width: 100%` property as I would expect.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to resolve it, if possible keeping the grid implementation (I know there are alternatives to centering things like this but I'd like to try to get this method working, out of curiosity more than anything else!)

Comment: Don't know enough to write an answer, but I believe it is essentially setting the width of the inner div to 1/3 of the grid and then adding 30px padding.

Comment: OK, not quite 1/3rd, but it is centering the content (splitting the space evenly between the two sides) and then adding on 30px padding for both sides. It _looks_ like it is adding on the 60px of left/right padding just to the right side, but it's because the padding is applying to the whole div whereas the text within the div is actually being centered _within the grid area_. See this screenshot with grid areas turned on in the browser dev tools: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ticCD.png (leaving this as a comment since I don't know at the moment how to fix it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `place-content` you can use `place-self` on the grid item.

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  background: black;
  display: grid;
}

.inner {
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  place-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Some content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "instead of using `place-content`"? Aside from that, this answer could benefit from an explanation as to why this solves the problem.

Comment: yes, it should be `place-content`. updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use flex instead of grid, which allow you to do so really easily.

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Some content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you remove the max-width property from OP's code? Aside from that, this answer could benefit from an explanation as to why/how this works, whereas OP's code doesn't.